# How to implement AngularJS session with PHP backend and token

Tags: php, angularjs, session

I'm developing an AngularJs application with PHP backend, I implemented the authentication step, and now I'm trying to display data of authenticated user in another view after authentication. I can't display user data. And I get this error in display.php file: Undefined index: token, please can you help me, I can't progress in my application?

login.php

```
<?php  
session_start();
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));

 $connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "test");  

 if(count($data) > 0)  

 { 

$Email=mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $data->Email);
$password=mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $data->password);

$query = 'SELECT * FROM `client` WHERE (EmailClient = "'.$Email.'" AND   password= "'.$password.'")';

$q = mysqli_query($connect , $query);

if(mysqli_num_rows($q) > 0 )
  { 
       $token = md5($Email.time()."51395+81519851");
       $query = "UPDATE client SET token = '".$token."' WHERE EmailClient = '".$Email."'";
       mysqli_query($connect , $query);
       $_SESSION["logged_in"] = true; 
       $_SESSION["token"] = $token; 
       $result['message'] ='Logged In';
       $result['email'] =$Email;
       $result['token'] = $token;

       $resultstring=json_encode($result);
       $resultstring=str_replace("null", '""', $resultstring);
       echo $resultstring;
       exit;
  }

       $result['message'] ='The username or password are incorrect!';

$resultstring = json_encode($result);
$resultstring = str_replace("null",'""',$resultstring);
echo $resultstring;
exit;
}

?>
```

display.php

```
<?php  
session_start();
 $connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "test");  

 $output = array();  
 $query = "SELECT Name,Adresse FROM client WHERE token = '".$_SESSION['token']."'";
 $result = mysqli_query($connect, $query);  
 if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0)  
 {  
      while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))  
      {  
           $output[] = $row;  
      }  
      echo json_encode($output);  
 }  

 ?>
```

Comment: *Never store passwords in clear text!*. Only store password hashes! Use PHP's [`password_hash()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) and [`password_verify()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php) . If you're running a PHP version lower than 5.5 (which I _really_ hope you aren't), you can use the [password_compat library](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat) to get the same functionallity.

Comment: Ok. Thank you @MagnusEriksson

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not with your PHP script but with the angular itself, you need to send token using angular $http module and set header something like

> Authorization : Bearer [token]

and the fetch header information in disply.php to get your token value.

if you want to do it by session you can use $httpProvider module in angular.

hope this will help you.

Comment: I am beginner with wangularJS , Can you explain more please!

Comment: Are you running your frontend(angular and HTML) and Backend(PHP) on same server or different server?

Comment: On the same serve

Comment: Can you provide the angular code where you are fetching the user data (service module).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45213890/how-to-get-authenticated-user-data-using-angularjs-and-php-backend! here is the angular and php code. Thank you